# How to encrypt and decrypt data over the internet?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a C# Application which connects to mongodb. The database is on a different server. I have to access it over internet. How can I encrypt and decrypt the data?

Comment: I am new and dont know where to start looking any suggestion in the right direction will be helpful.

Comment: where can i use ssl ? mean i have a C# application on my desktop and its connecting to database over internet.

Comment: take a look at this post [http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/encrypting-with-mongo](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/encrypting-with-mongo). According to that post, MongoDB does not support SSL. As far as encrypting/decrypting data, look at the [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) classes. You can encrypt it before sending it to the DB and decrypt when you get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH tunnels or a VPN.

`ssh -f user@remote_server -L 27017:localhost:27017 -N`

- The -f tells ssh to go into the background just before it executes
  the command.
- This is followed by the username and server you are logging into.
- The -L 27017:personal-server.com:27017 is in the form of -L
  local-port:host:remote-port.
- Finally the -N instructs OpenSSH to not execute a command on the
  remote system.

[source](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html)